# Not possible load assembly due to version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference, assemblies

I have this package, **Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization**, that uses **Antlr3**.

Once i installed it, **Antlr3** came in version **3.4.1.9004**.

After that i was checking my installed packages for updates and, by mistake, i updated the **Antlr3** to **3.5.0.2**. Now, even if i remove all of it, all the packages and reinstall the **Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization** i still get an error screen because it's referring to the newer version of **Antlr3** instead of the old one.

I already tried several other things but nothings seems to solve the problem.

Where can i remove the reference ?

My main error is this one:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The assembly's manifest definition does not match the located assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Comment: Did you try a Build->Clean and then a Build->Rebuild on the solution?

Comment: Yeah, already tried that, also tried remove all the package using prompt and by NuGet Package Control

Comment: Since you tried things... Can you post fusion log so it is clear which reference is actually causing problems?

Comment: have you tried binding redirect in config https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Alexei, how can i get the fusion log ?

Comment: There many step-by-step guides... https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+can+i+get+the+fusion+log should give you at least some (ignoring Ford Fusion).

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexei, i managed to fix it using the binding redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by binding it on web.config, changing the version to the one i wanted.

After that i tried removing everything from the project, close VS, remove dll's and add one at a time, it also worked.